# Value pair url modeling for subpages via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ok, currently to get the URL in the format I want I use this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^user.php/([0-9]+)/?$          user.php?id=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^user.php/edit/([0-9]+)/?$     user.php?id=$1&type=edit    [NC,L]
```

Urls, redirect to

```
domain/user/7/      -> domain/user?id=7
domain/user/edit/7/ -> domain/user?id=7&type=edit
```

Works fine, but I want to be able to do better value pair urls instead of just strict matches.

An example is

```
domain/user/key/value/key/value/key/value/
    -> domain/user.php?key=value&key=value&key=value
```

I was looking at

[.htaccess rewrite to convert directories into /key/value/key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794441/htaccess-rewrite-to-convert-directories-into-key-value-key-value)

The example works well if you just want to redirect from the main path, ie localhost/index.php, but I want to only be triggered when it's domain/user and I couldn't get it to match with using 'user' as the trigger

My current .htaccess

```
# Pretty url's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule    ^user.php/([0-9]+)/?$          user.php?id=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^user.php/edit/([0-9]+)/?$     user.php?id=$1&type=edit    [NC,L]
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ok this is working for me

RewriteRule ^(user.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(user)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]

# Pretty url's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

URL

```
/user/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4
```

Outputs

```
Array ( [n4] => v4 [n3] => v3 [n2] => v2 [n1] => v1 )
```

anubhava, you da man :)

Answer (score 1):

`Deja vu time`!!! I wrote that answer sometime back :P

Here is what you can do for your case:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(user)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(user)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule    ^user.php/([0-9]+)/?$          user.php?id=$1    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^user.php/edit/([0-9]+)/?$     user.php?id=$1&type=edit    [NC,L]   

# Pretty url's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Using these rules a URL of `/user/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4` will be INTERNALLY forwarded to `/user.php?n4=v4&n3=v3&n2=v2&n1=v1 treating each pair of URL segments separated by / as a name-value pair for`QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: Hey bro, the help is most appreciated. On my user.php page I'm testing the ouput a simple print_r($_REQUEST), but it's coming up empty when using a url like

www.domain.com/user/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4

Any ideas?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.